# My android sqlite database app gets close when I search the name which does not exist in the table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Here is a code/method to find if some name exists in the table or not..

```
Contact getContact(String name) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_NAME + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(name) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));

    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    // return contact
    return contact;
}
```

I already have a function to get all names in an arrayList. I can call it before calling the above function to solve my problem. But I want to ask about is there any other (straight) way to do it

Comment: where is the logcat? .. please provide it for us to see what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `cursor.moveToFirst()` it will return `true` if there is a valid result there, or `false` in the case no results are found. If `cursor.moveToFirst()` returns `false`, then calling any of the `getXXX()` methods will fail.

Try something like this:

```
if( cursor.moveToFirst() )
{
    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
}
cursor.close();
```

Note that the `Cursor` returned from `SQLiteDatabase.query` is guaranteed to be *non-null*.

Comment: I've seen `query` return a null cursor, though I wasn't able to figure out the exact circumstances of it. +1 for `moveToFirst` returning false, though--that's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cursor == null)
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Records Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_NAME + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(name) }, null, null, null, null);
           if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
         do {
            Double lat = cursor.getDouble(2);
            Double lon = cursor.getDouble(1);
           } while (trackCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code for getting all the contacts in a list from the table...

```
/**
 * Getting all the contacts in the database
 */
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}
```

Then it is invoked in another function that returns "true" if name is present in the table "false" otherwise...

```
    /**
     * checks if name already present in the database
     * @param name
     * @return
     */
    public boolean checkDbData(String name){
        List<Contact> contactList =getAllContacts();
        boolean checkName = false ;

        for(Contact cn: contactList){
            String dbName = cn.getName();
            if(name.equals(dbName)){
                checkName = true ;
            }               
        }

        return checkName;
    }
```

And if this function returns "true", then the above given function is invoked to get the contacti.e.

```
Contact getContact(String name) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
        KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_NAME + "=?",
        new String[] { String.valueOf(name) }, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));

db.close();
cursor.close();
// return contact
return contact;
```

}

Note: we can also get this contact from the contactList, both can be used to get the required contact (i.e. "name" in this case)